# Set STS Header on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a static site which is hosted behind an azure cdn. I'd like to set the `Strict-Transport-Security` header, but if I try:

```
$blobProperties = @{
    "x-ms-meta-Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
};

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Properties $blobProperties (other flag omitted for clarity)
```

This throws the error

`x-ms-meta-Strict-Transport-Security' with value 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' is invalid`

Is it possible to set the header?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a static site which is hosted behind an azure cdn. I'd like to
>   set the Strict-Transport-Security header. Is it possible to set the
>   header?

AFAIK, No. It is not possible to set this header. Blob Storage allows you to set certain HTTP headers in properties (like Cache-Control, Content-Type etc.) and this particular header is not one of them.

I read a bit about this header and from what I understand that this header enforces the use of `HTTPS` protocol. By default blob content can be served via both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocol.

If you wish to enforce `HTTPS` only protocol, I would recommend using `Shared Access Signature` on your blobs and use `Protocol Restriction` there. Please see this link for more information regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#shared-access-signature-parameters.

Comment: It's not just about having a connection via ssl, but also about communicating to the browser to never try and connect via http. It prevent's a specific class of mitm attacks. I may side step the whole issue and get the top level domain added to https://hstspreload.org